# Drawing a row of images using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Im following the python crash course book, and there's a small task where we have to display images on a pygame window. I've been able to complete displaying images as part of a larger piece of code, but trying to figure it out for this small task has proven difficult.

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class StarGame:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Starry Night")
        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_stars()

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self.stars.draw(self.screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()


    def _create_stars(self):
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size

        # Find available space and find number of stars that
        # can fit in a row
        available_x = 1200 - 2 * star_width
        stars_per_row = available_x // (star_width * 2)

        # Create stars in that row
        for star_number in range(stars_per_row):
            self._create_star(star_number)

    def _create_star(self, star_number):
        star = Star(self)
        star_width, star_height = star.rect.size

        # Get horizontal position for star
        star.x = star_width + 2 * star_width * star_number
        star.rect.x = star.x

        # Add star to group
        self.stars.add(star)



class Star(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, star_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = star_game.screen

        # Load image of star
        self.image = pygame.image.load('star.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start star on top left of screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store star's position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    star_game = StarGame()
    star_game.run_game()
```

Looking over this code, the problem is probably something very simple, but I can't seem to figure out why it won't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I find it's always easier to isolate potential culprit to simplify a problem. 
start by commenting some code that seem to have no impact on the problem. Comment as much as you can to help you understand the impact of each part. Once you have done so, you will be able to see where the "problem" lies. I would suggest doing so (on your side) and then removing unnecessary code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`rect.x` and `.rect.y` stores the location of the image, but not its with and height.

Remove 2 lines of code to solve the issue:

```py
class Star(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, star_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = star_game.screen

        # Load image of star
        self.image = pygame.image.load('star.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start star on top left of screen
        # self.rect.x = self.rect.width   <--- DELETE
        # self.rect.y = self.rect.height  <--- DELETE

        # Store star's position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

The with and height of the rectangle is correctly set by `get_rect()`. [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).